# While running React Native Application on Simulator always picking a real device

Tags: react-native, xcode14

I am trying to run the React Native application using the following command.

```
npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 15 Pro Max"
```

This command works fine in my other projects but in my one project, it is Finding a booted device that is not even connected to my Mac and I am getting the following error.

[image: error]

I have tried the command after cleaning the build folder and removing and reinstalling pods but didn't work. Can anyone suggest a solution or workaround for this issue?